# PHP wildcard for files in folder

Tags: php, file

I have a `.pdf` file in a directory that needs to be viewed/downloaded but the `.pdf` file changes its filename every so often, so I was just wondering if there is anything I can do to make it a kind of wildcard so the button link changes to `/files/*.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
print_r(glob("/files/*.pdf"));
?>
```

Have a look at: [PHP glob() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info :) when I add the above code I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN)

Comment: Forgot a " at the end, sorry. :D

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [glob()](http://php.net/glob).